# how to Serialize Enumeration in Coherence

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

I am using coherence as a cache system with weblogic appserver. I have a class as below which contains two fields:

```
package com.org.cusomer;

public class OrderDetail {
    private String customerName;
    private int customerId;
    private CustomerType customerType;
    public enum Customertype {VIP, CAT_A,CAT_B}
}
```

for serializing the object to Coherence I serached and I understood I have to create a jar file associated with pof-config, cache-config and coherence-application.xml and I mentioned the below code in pof-config:

```
<user-type>
    <type-id>1004</type-id>
    <class-name>com.org.cusomer.OrderDetail</class-name>
</user-type>
```

moreover I added the annotation for the class and the fields,as below:

```
package com.org.cusomer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Portable
public class OrderDetail {
    @PortableProperty(0)
    private String customerName;

    @PortableProperty(0)
    private int customerId;
    private CustomerType customerType;
    public enum Customertype {VIP, CAT_A,CAT_B}
}
```

what should I do for the enum? It doesnt accept the @PortableProperty annotaion but when running the project it mentions that :
 "missing user-type for customerType"
Can anyone help me please?
Thanks a lot.